# How to fix error in Building Flutter FFI Plugin on Windows with CMake: MSB3073

Tags: flutter, dart, cmake

I'm trying to build libogg, libopus and libopusfile in my flutter ffi plugen. Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ffi_example VERSION 1.1.1)
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0077 NEW)
include(FetchContent)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
set(INSTALL_DOCS OFF)
set(INSTALL_PKG_CONFIG_MODULE OFF)
set(INSTALL_CMAKE_PACKAGE_MODULE OFF)

FetchContent_Declare(Ogg
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/xiph/ogg.git
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES Ogg
)
set(OPUS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY ON)
set(OPUS_BUILD_TESTING OFF)
set(OPUS_CUSTOM_MODES OFF)
set(OPUS_BUILD_PROGRAMS OFF)
set(OPUS_DISABLE_INTRINSICS ON)
set(OPUS_FIXED_POINT ON)
set(OPUS_ENABLE_FLOAT_API OFF)
set(OPUS_FLOAT_APPROX OFF)
set(OPUS_INSTALL_PKG_CONFIG_MODULE OFF)
set(OPUS_INSTALL_CMAKE_CONFIG_MODULE OFF)
FetchContent_Declare(Opus
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/xiph/opus.git
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES Opus
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Ogg Opus)
set(OP_DISABLE_HTTP ON)
set(OP_DISABLE_FLOAT_API ON)
set(OP_FIXED_POINT ON)
set(OP_DISABLE_EXAMPLES ON)
set(OP_DISABLE_DOCS ON)
if(WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS  True)
endif()
set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES True)
FetchContent_Declare(Opusfile
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/xiph/opusfile.git
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES Opusfile
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Opusfile)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RULES False)
```

Part of my windows specific `CMakeLists.txt` to pull in the needed package:

```
# external build triggered from this build file.
find_package(Opusfile)
set(whatever_bundled_libraries
  # Defined in ../src/CMakeLists.txt.
  # This can be changed to accommodate different builds.
  $<TARGET_FILE:OpusFile::opusfile>
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

I just wanted to see if this works so I can continue, however, running `flutter build windows` outputs this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\username\projects\whatever\example\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
Building Windows application...                                   173.8s
Build process failed.
```

I am not sure what's going wrong here and would appreciate any help. Thanks.